# Hashed or Encrypted passwords are not supported with auto-generated keys

Tags: asp.net-membership

I have create a Membership provider and changed my web.config to

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
     <clear/>
     <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
          type="Khafan.Providers.SqlMembershipProvider"
          connectionStringName="KhafanConnectionString"  
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"             
          passwordAttemptWindow="10"
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="4"
          passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
          passwordFormat="Hashed"
          enablePasswordReset="true"
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false"             
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
          requiresUniqueEmail="true" />
   </providers>
 </membership>
```

but now, whenever I try to browse to security page of ASP.Net Configuration it gives me the following error:

**Hashed or Encrypted passwords are not supported with auto-generated keys**

In my database I have used Identity for my PKs. I don't know it is the problem or not. But if it is, how can I solve it? I don't want to change Identity values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is because you are hashing passwords but haven't set specific keys in your web.config. There's a "key generator" snippet in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx), run it twice and shove them in your web.config as:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey  
    validationKey="<blah>"           
    decryptionKey="<blah>"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
    />
```

And that should sort you out. It's like this because otherwise you could take your membership database/app to another machine and none of your passwords would work, as the auto generated machine keys would be different :-)

Comment: Or just use this online tool: http://www.developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx

Comment: Above link is broken, but here's another: http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: Will I need to do this even if I am using a custom hashing algorithm?  And creating user from one application and try to login from a diff application the application could be hosted on same or may be different machines. Both the application use the "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" and whose "passwordFormat" property is "Hashed" and "hashAlgorithmType" property of "membership" tag is "CustomPbkdf2Hash".

Answer (score 4):

Was a bit of a schlep to go hunting for the "key generator" snippet in the 
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) Steven Robbins referred to in his answer, so I am adding it here for quick reference. So this is not a standalone answer. It is supplemental to the accepted answer.

**FROM MSDN**

> The following code shows how to
>   generate random key values. Compile
>   the code to create a console
>   application, and then pass the
>   required key size as a command line
>   argument expressed as the desired
>   number of hexadecimal characters. Each
>   byte is represented by two hexadecimal
>   characters; therefore, to request a
>   32-byte key, pass 64 as a command line
>   argument. If you do not specify an
>   argument, the code returns a 128
>   hexadecimal character (64-byte) key.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class App {
  static void Main(string[] argv) {
    int len = 128;
    if (argv.Length > 0)
      len = int.Parse(argv[0]);
    byte[] buff = new byte[len/2];
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new 
                            RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    rng.GetBytes(buff);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i=0; i<buff.Length; i++)
      sb.Append(string.Format("{0:X2}", buff[i]));
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
  }
}
```

Also, `<machineKey>` goes inside of `<system.web>`, like this:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey
        validationKey=""
        decryptionKey=""
        validation="SHA1"
        decryption="AES"
/>
```