# Why I can't hash the password in my seed method?

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to use my seed method below to create an user when my database is created:

```
protected override void Seed(CodingCraftMod1Ex4AuthMembershipContext context)
{
    string password = PasswordsHelper.EncodePassword("123456", System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat.Hashed);

    var user = new CustomUser
    {
        CustomUserId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Name = "MyUser",
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        LastModified = DateTime.Now
    };

    context.CustomUsers.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var membership = new Membership
    {
        MembershipId = Guid.NewGuid(),
        CustomUser = user,
        Password = password,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
        LastModified = DateTime.Now,
    };

    context.Memberships.Add(membership);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But I get this error:

> Hashed or encrypted passwords are not supported with auto-generated keys

I already [found this question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546861/hashed-or-encrypted-passwords-are-not-supported-with-auto-generated-keys). But I'm already using the machineKey element, like this:

```
<machineKey   validationKey="13687AD58719815734D5ECA97AADA159F4084FE994E32192243818A714DD6BC763B9F3D8AE7B3A7858A268D8EAAB37BF5031E77E5971C82BC1ACEA478C76C6CF" 
decryptionKey="A39F3B62B3CAAD3F75358197CA1D880BA3F392BE79AE4E91D2A09219D82A6978"
validation="SHA1" 
decryption="AES" />
```

I used [this online tool](http://developmentnow.com/articles/machinekey_generator.aspx) to generate the keys.

Comment: Is your Migration/DataAccess project belongs to another project and WebHost just refers to it? If yes  - add machineKey to these project and run seed again

Comment: No, it's not belongs to another project.